# The motion of a mass is described by $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + x+x^3 = 0$. Determine how solutions of this equation behave.

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

So far this is what I have:

First off, let $\dot x = y$ and $\dot y = -x-x^3$. Then the DE can be written as
$$\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4} = H(x,y)$$

This is Newtonian, so consider the following:

$$U(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4}$$
$$U'(x) = x+x^3$$

This shows that $U'(x) = 0$ means that $x = 0$. Now

$$U''(x) = 1 + 3x^2$$

So $U''(0) = 1 > 0$ which implies that we have a min at $x = 0$. This implies that we have a center at $x =0$.

Is there more that I can add to this without explicitly using software? This is a question from a former PhD qualifying exam, so I'm trying to figure out what they may be expecting.

Comment: Jacobi, you say?  You can express the solutions in "closed form" using the Jacobi $\text{sn}$ function.

Comment: If I understand the Wikipedia article correctly on Jacobi sn functions, then I don't think that's what they're expecting on our exam. This is helpful though! Any and all ideas are always welcome!

Comment: Specifically, it can be written as $x = \pm \sqrt{2c^2-2} \;\text{sn}\left(c (t - t_0), \sqrt{1/c^2-1}\right)$.

Comment: But if this is a differential equations or dynamical systems exam rather than an elliptic functions exam, they are probably looking for the fact that all solutions (other than the constant $0$) are periodic.

Comment: For a fixed $x$, $H(x,y)$ (strictly) in/decreases to $\infty$ as $y\to\pm\infty$. Similarly for $x$, $y$ interchanged. So the level sets of $H$ are bounded. $H(0,0)=0$, so nontrivial level sets are homeomorphic to the circle (indeed, by the implicit function theorem, they are diffeomorphic). No nontrivial level set contains an equilibrium, hence, being invariant, it must be a periodic orbit. Consequently, $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is foliated by periodic orbits. Further, you can observe some symmetries: $H(-x,y)=H(x,y)=H(x,-y)$. How does this "translate" into the behavior of solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As additional information you can approximate the period of small oscillatins. Consider the solution curve through $(x,y)=(x_0,0)$, $x_0$ small. Then with the Hamiltionian we get
$$
y^2+x^2+\frac12x^4=x_0^2+\frac12x_0^4
\\
\dot x^2=y^2=(x_0^2-x^2)\left(1+\frac12(x_0^2+x^2)\right).
$$
One quarter of the period can be computed as the integral
\begin{align}
\frac{T}4&=\int_0^{x_0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x_0^2-x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac12(x_0^2+x^2)}}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{x_0^2}2(1+z^2)}}
\\[1em]
&=\int_0^1\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sqrt{1+x_0^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{x_0^2(1-z^2)}{2(1+x_0^2)}}}
\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}\frac{x_0^{2k}}{8^k(1+x_0^2)^{k+\frac12}}\int_0^1(1-z^2)^{k-\frac12}\,dz
\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x_0^2}}\int_0^1\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}
   +\frac{x_0^2}{4(1+x_0^2)^{\frac32}}\int_0^1\sqrt{1-z^2}\,dz+O(x_0^4)\\[1em]
&=\frac\pi{2\sqrt{1+x_0^2}}+\frac{\pi x_0^2}{16(1+x_0^2)^{\frac32}}+O(x_0^4).
\end{align}
The series expansion was done using the binomial series
$$
(1-u)^{-1/2}=\sum\binom{-1/2}k(-u)^k=\sum\binom{2k}{k}\left(\frac u4\right)^k
$$